# Black Body Golf Balls

Tags: thermal-radiation, thought-experiment

The surface of a golf ball has about 35% more surface area (than a similar sphere) due to its dimples. So my question is simple, given identical radius, ideal black body material, and temperature:

**Would this increased surface area allow a black body golf ball to radiate more than its smooth counterpart?**

I'd like to know if the golf ball will be able to radiate its energy more quickly than the smooth sphere, so total power radiated away from the objects is what I'm interested in. By "radiated away" from the object I mean not *toward* it. This is energy lost by the object per unit time. There is no coolant medium, advection, convection, or conduction (to a separate object). Radiation *only*.

Comment: Its a beautiful, crazy idea!

Comment: Yes, the [Stefan-Boltzmann law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stefan%E2%80%93Boltzmann_law) is not unique to spheres...

Comment: No. Black-body radiation does not leave normal to the surface. An improvidently aimed ray leaving the surface at the bottom of a "dimple" may be re-absorbed by the dimple wall. I haven't done the maths on it but I strongly suspect it will come out that a golf ball radiates the same as if the dimples were "plugged" up to the "level" of the circle (and this would be slightly less than a sphere of the same radius).

Comment: @lemon Clearly more area means more radiation, but as indicated in the final sentence, I'm interested in what's radiated *away* from the object.

Comment: @Atsby You think the concavity of the dimples would make them radiate no better than a disc?

Comment: @Samuel Yes. I suck at maths but I think intuitively that the radiated power will be proportional to integrating the -silhouette- of the object seen from every point on an enclosing/enveloping sphere. Clearly the silhouette of a "dimple" is indistinguishable from a disc plugging the circumference of the dimple, at every point on the enclosing/enveloping sphere.

Comment: You could use a cube of the same volume. It has more surface area and none of its rays will be re-absorbed.

Comment: @Azad If I was going to change the shape I'd go for a tetrahedron. It's more of an improvement over the cube than the cube was over the sphere.

Comment: Gawsh,  it's just a simple integral over the "horizon" seen by each point in the dimple.  :-)

Comment: Best shape is obviously a pancake (the flatter the better).

Comment: @Samuel Since you already know more area = more radiation I am trying to get a grip on the question. Would it be equivalent to your question to ask "Do a bowl and a sphere with the same surface area have the same power emitted?" I.e. are you basically asking about radiation from concave surfaces?

Comment: @pentane The question is whether surface features can increase the radiated energy *away* from an object. Take the two objects described, will the energy flux through an enveloping surface be higher for the smooth sphere or for the higher surface area golf ball?

Comment: If the dimples do help, then how much does the [coast of Great Britain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coastline_paradox) radiate?

Comment: @JiK About 140 kilopeople.

Comment: @Samuel by *away* do you mean that you exclude radiation which hits another part of the surface of the object after being emitted by the object?

Comment: @pentane Yes, of course. If the radiation was absorbed by the object then it was radiated *toward* the object, not away from it.

Comment: assuming the ball is a perfect radiator in an isolated vacuum ( "Radiation only" ), is its white color playing some role in the balance of the surface absorptions and emissions ?

Comment: @igael This is a black body golf ball, so it absorbs all incident light. Its perceived color will depend on its temperature; it may glow red or white if it is hot enough, but if at room temperature it will be pitch black even when illuminated.

Comment: Good question, great responses and discussion. A good advert for Physics SE I would say.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Mark is correct](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/186363/45770), and my discussion with him ultimately led to an understanding, but I feel his answer lacks an intuitive approach or clear statement as to *why* he is correct. The simple and relevant, though not explicitly stated, portion of his answer is: emitted or absorbed radiation is dependent on the *cross sectional area* and not the surface area.

By using a gaussian surface around the object to determine the flux of radiation leaving the object we can visualize *why* this is the case.

[image]

Looking at the object from each point on the gaussian surface, its surface contours can not be determined, only its outline. Being a perfect black body, it would also appear uniform in intensity. The radiation it receives from the sphere does not depend on the surface area it sees, but rather the cross sectional area. This is true for every point on the gaussian surface.

Therefore, the radiation emitted away from the object, in total, does not depend on the surface area at all, but the integration of all the cross sections visible from every point on the gaussian surface.

For the case of a dimple, there is no point on the gaussian surface that will see an increase in cross sectional area. The surface area has increased, but the cross sectional area, and therefore radiation output, can only decrease in this case.

[image]

This works the other way too, of course, and can be observed clearly when looking at radiation delivered from the Sun to a spherical planet which is a great distance from the Sun. As pictured here:

[image]
[$_{Source}$](http://eesc.columbia.edu/courses/ees/climate/lectures/gh_kushnir.html)

This is further described by principles of irradiance. As described on [this website](http://omlc.org/education/ece532/class1/fluencerate.html):

> The surface area of the sphere is not the factor that determines the amount of absorbed power. Rather, it is the cross-sectional area A which provides the "target size" for intercepting the [radiation]...

As absorbing or emitting is just a direction change, it's clear that surface area is not a factor for emitting radiation either.

Answer (score 11):

Consider a smooth spherical shell. The outside of the shell admits no energy transfer via radiation or any other means, so that the shell and its interior form an isolated system. The shell is at temperature $T$. Its inside surface is a perfect black body.

Next put a smooth solid sphere, also a perfect black body, in the center of the shell, also at temperature $T$. It will absorb radiation from the inside surface of the shell and will also emit radiation, all of which is absorbed by the shell. Because the shell and ball are at the same temperature, they cannot exchange net heat, so the sphere absorbs and emits radiation at the same rate.

Next replace the sphere with a perfect black body golf ball of equal cross section to the sphere. This ball absorbs the same amount of radiation from the shell as the sphere did simply because it absorbs all the radiation that hits it. The golf ball, like the solid sphere, must emit and absorb the same amount of radiation because otherwise heat would flow between bodies of equal temperature. Therefore, the golf ball emits the same amount of radiation as the sphere.

If you start with a sphere and put dimples in it, you've actually reduced the cross-section a bit because the caps of the dimples are gone, so such a dimpled sphere would radiate slightly less than before.

Comment: Next, replace the golf ball with a sphere (or black body potato), that has half the diameter, at temperature $T$. It will also remain at temperature $T$, because otherwise there would be heat flow between two objects at the same temperature. It also, as a black body, will absorb all radiation that hits it. Is that not valid? I can see that this proves that energy is conserved, but nothing about a black body golf ball.

Comment: I can't tell what you're asking, sorry. My answer provides a complete explanation of why the golf ball will not radiate more energy. What specific part of it do you not understand? Your question about a ball of smaller radius is a non-sequitur to me. Yes, a smaller ball will indeed remain at the same temperature, but I don't get why you care.

Comment: I bring up the smaller sphere because the conditions inside the containing sphere appear to not depend on surface area or shape, even when such an object would be different outside those conditions, so this thought experiment can't be used to demonstrate anything about them. A larger sphere inside would also not change temperature, so we can't tell if the golf ball is or isn't radiating more.

Comment: I will have to guess at what you're saying because it is extremely difficult to understand you. My best guess is that you have completely ignored the crucial part of my argument - that the golf ball and the sphere absorb the same amount of radiation as each other because they have the same cross-section. A small sphere clearly does not absorb the same amount of radiation as a large sphere, so the argument in my answer does not indicate that a small and large sphere would radiate the same amount as you appear to be implying.

Comment: Suppose the sphere absorbs power $p_s$. Then, in order to remain the same temperature, it must also radiate power $p_s$. Because the golf ball is very nearly the same shape and size as the sphere, it absorbs very nearly power $p_s$, and so it emits very nearly $p_s$, so the golf ball and sphere emit and absorb very nearly the same power. The only difference is that adding dimples actually makes the golf ball's cross section very slightly smaller so it absorbs/emits slightly less than $p_s$. A very small sphere would absorb much less than $p_s$ and so would radiate much less.

Comment: You say same amount of radiation in the answer and you now say it's a different amount of radiation (as all the power is in the form of radiation). The cross-sectional area may be smaller, but I don't see how it matters. The cross-sectional surface area (perimeter) is still larger for a golf ball. Since the outside is all that is interacting with the containing sphere I don't see why the volume (or cross-sectional area) matters.

Comment: Based on your comment, you are clearly unwilling to read my answer carefully; I said very, very plainly in my original answer that if you start with a sphere and add dimples, the emitted radiation will go down very slightly. Your denial of that means you are not truly attempting to understand what I wrote.

Comment: The cross section of an object determines what radiation it absorbs from the shell. I find this to be extremely obvious and do not see how it would be possible for you to fail to understand it. Your statement about "cross-sectional surface area (perimeter)" is very confusing. I don't know what you mean by that. I am referring to the cross-sectional area because it determines how much radiation is absorbed from the shell. I am not discussing the perimeter or the surface area.

Comment: I read your answer carefully, it contradicts itself, don't pin that on me. A cross section is a 2D plane of a 3D object, surface *area* becomes the surface *line*, properly known as the perimeter. You statement that the "cross section of an object determines what radiation it absorbs from the shell" would be an excellent answer to the question if you could support it. It's the assumption that you've included as a known fact which has caused this confusion.

Comment: No, the answer does not contradict itself. It discusses two scenarios: one in which the golf ball has exactly the same cross section as the sphere, and one in which the golf ball starts out the same as the sphere and has dimples added. Since those scenarios are different, they have different answers. The cross section determines what radiation is absorbed from the shell because it determines what lines of sight from the shell are blocked by the sphere. I don't understand how this isn't obvious.

Comment: It doesn't determine that though. If I make the sphere hollow, or give it a very small opening like the letter C, it has a significantly smaller cross sectional area but has the same lines of sight. I don't see how that isn't obvious.

Comment: Perhaps you are confused about the word "cross section". Your statement is simply wrong.

Comment: Your descriptions are insufficient due to the "this is obvious" assumptions and the conclusions which simply beg the question, this makes you a rather infuriating person to communicate with. However, you are ultimately correct. I've found a more intuitive description to what you're trying to describe [here](http://omlc.org/education/ece532/class1/fluencerate.html).

Comment: "Therefore the golf ball emits the same amount of radiation as the sphere". This statement needs more proof. If I put any thermal emitter inside your shell it will emit as much radiation as it absorbs. Indeed if it is a bb it emits $\sigma T^4$ per unit of emitting area. Thus you can equally argue that the golf ball emits more (it is just that some of it is reabsorbed). I.e. I think the equality applies to flux through a sphere that encloses the golf ball. Which to be fair, does appear to be what the OP asks.

Answer (score 5):

No, the golf ball would not radiate more.  At http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stefan%E2%80%93Boltzmann_law, after deriving the Stefan-Boltzmann law, it says:

> Finally, this proof started out only considering a small flat surface. However, any differentiable surface can be approximated by a bunch of small flat surfaces. So long as the geometry of the surface does not cause the blackbody to reabsorb its own radiation, the total energy radiated is just the sum of the energies radiated by each surface; and the total surface area is just the sum of the areas of each surface—so this law holds for all convex blackbodies, too, so long as the surface has the same temperature throughout. The law extends to radiation from non-convex bodies by using the fact that the convex hull of a black body radiates as though it were itself a black body.

Thus, the convex hull of the golf ball is the surface that is relevant for calculating the total radiated energy.  In other words, a sphere (EDIT: actually, the convex hull of the golf ball is the golf ball with the dimples replaced by discs, which has a surface area that is less than a sphere of the same radius)

Comment: I'm not sure about *the convex hull of a black body radiates as though it were itself a black body*. Consider a black string of length $L$ and radius $R$ such that $L \ggg R$. Ignoring the tiny ends, the power radiated by the string is $2\pi LR\sigma T^4$. Now join an identical string to the first at the middle and arrange the strings to form an X. I would think the radiated power is now $4\pi LR\sigma T^4$, less a little bit for self-impingement. The power radiated by the convex hull is $L^2 \sigma T^4$, which is much greater than that radiated by the two strings.

Comment: Bottom line: This answer is based on yet another wikipedia article that needs to be tagged with "citation needed".

Comment: One should apply the proof mentioned to the actual surface, not to the apparent surface filled in with discs. The "small flat surfaces" would conform to the dimples as well as to the convex hull. The paragraph quoted applies a proof for flat surfaces to convex surfaces, and then says "The law extends to radiation from non-convex bodies..."  A golf ball with concave depressions should also be included as a black body.  I don't understand what basis there is to say that a golf ball with its greater surface area would radiate no more than a smooth sphere.  I may be dense on this point.

Answer (score 4):

Great question - harkens back to the days when we discussed why a tiny
hole in a hot cavity is the perfect radiator and such things. Makes you
think, which is what's great about it!

> Would this increased surface area allow a black body golf ball to
>   radiate more than its smooth counterpart?

The correct answer is no, it would radiate a tiny bit less than for a
perfectly spherical golf ball, depending on how far away you are. If
Bubba Watson is about to strike a ball on the tee directly your way, you
want to be at a safe distance. How far? Let's say at least half a
kilometer, i.e., 500m.

A good reference for understanding blackbody radiation and associated
issues (like the "principle of detailed balance" and "Lambert's Law",
which is essentially $\cos(\theta)$) is your trusty copy of Reif's
"Fundamentals of Statistical and Thermal Physics".

Imagine something that's not quite a sphere - let's say two spheres
connected by a long ultra-thin (massless) wire, just enough to call the
arrangement a single body. Will this combination radiate more than a
single sphere? Of course! But not along the line joining the two
spheres, since one will be occluded by the other.

So the shape of the radiator does matter. Now let's consider the golf
ball. The dimples are concave, so let's start with a single small dimple
at the north pole of an otherwise smoothly spherical ball. If you are on
the $z$-axis, directly above the north pole, you see the same
cross-section ($\pi R^2$, where $R$ is the radius of the ball) radiating
towards you. To get the exact amount of radiation you have to integrate
over the surface facing you, using "Lambert's Law" alluded to above, and
get the amount of radiation. The only difference from the unblemished
smooth spherical golf ball case is that the dented part of the surface
is slightly farther away from the observer.

To do the integral over the surface for the amount of radiation headed
in a particular direction (towards the observer) you have to multiply
the surface area element by $\cos(\theta)$, which is the dot product of
the unit direction vector $\hat n$ and the area element $d\vec A$. This
is what turns the spherical area of $2\pi R^2$ into a projected   area of
$\pi R^2$.

The only difference for the case of a real golf ball, and an observer
viewing it from a random direction, is that the radiating surfaces are
slightly farther away due to the dimples. But this is a tiny effect. If
the dimples have an effective depth $d$, then for an observer at a
distance $L$ large compared to the size    of the ball the reduction in
radiation will be the 35% dimple area estimate times $(1-d^2/L^2)$. If we estimate the effective depth to be half a millimeter, then at 500m we get roughly 1/3 of $10^{-12}$ less radiation compared to the perfectly spherical ball - a truly tiny effect.

Answer (score 2):

I had thought that a golf ball would radiate a tiny bit more energy per unit time away from itself than its smooth counterpart.  Although the rate of radiation per unit surface area is the same for both, it seemed to me that the greater surface area of the golf ball, and the configuration of the dimples in its surface, would result in slightly more energy being radiated away than from a smooth sphere of equal radius.

If each dimple in the golf ball, I thought, were no greater than an inverted hemisphere of whatever radius describes the sphere of which it is a cap, more than 50% of radiation emitted by the surface inside the dimple would be radiated away from the golf ball.

Consider a perpendicular to the tangent at each point on the surface of the dimple.  All perpendiculars with the exception of those at the horizon of the dimple will clear the horizon.  Thus, they will not be reabsorbed.

Consider all other possible angles of radiation at each point on the surface of the dimple.  50% of the angles at the lip of the dimple will be reabsorbed.  As the points descend into the dimple, the 50% reabsorption rate for all angles OTHER THAN perpendicular to a tangent to the surface of the dimple will be maintained.

I thought that to the extent perpendiculars to tangents at the dimple surfaces exceed perpendiculars to tangents at the continuous spherical surface that would cover the dimple, they would represent extra energy radiated per unit time by a golf ball.

I failed to realize that the perpendiculars emanating from the dimple would be matched in number by points on the smooth surface of a sphere where the dimple would have been.

Radiation from a black body is described by the Stefan/Boltzmann Law (or Stefan's Law), and by Wien's Law.  Wien's law says that the frequency of radiated energy increases with temperature.  I don't think that's important for this problem.

Stefan's Law, which governs total thermodynamic radiation from any black body regardless of shape, is important for this problem.  It says that the total energy of heat, across all wavelengths, radiated per unit time, PER UNIT SURFACE AREA, is proportional only to the thermodynamic temperature (taken to the 4th power) of the black body.

Radiant exitance (or radiant flux) emitted from a given surface area = P = dE/dt = ((2*pi^5*k^4)/(15*c^2*h^3)) * A * T^4, where "k" is the Boltzmann constant, "c" is speed of light in a vacuum, "h" is Planck's constant, "A" is surface area, and "T" is thermodynamic temperature of the black body in degrees Kelvin.  I left out the emissivity index, which we assume to be 1 as it's a black body, and the ambient temperature, which we assume will have no effect on this problem.

As you can see, the only variables for amount of power emitted per unit time are surface area and temperature.

But although a golf ball has more surface area, and is bound to radiate more energy per unit time per unit surface, all the excess energy will be reabsorbed by the golf ball.  Surface area matters.  The greater the surface area, the more total heat will be radiated per second.  But cross section trumps surface area for energy radiated away and not reabsorbed.

Comment: link for Stefan Boltzmann law http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/thermo/stefan.html

Comment: "I don't think that the sides of the dimples will re-absorb radiated heat in any significant amount as long as the dimples are not too deep" -- but if the dimples weren't deep, there would be no change in surface area either. Both effects vanish in the limit of infinitesimal dimples.

Comment: The question is about *radiated* energy, not convected energy. There is no coolant medium involved, the answer would be rather trivial if it were. I was very specific about saying radiated energy and tagging with [tag:thermal-radiation], but I'll update the question to be more explicit.

Comment: @Samuel: You are right, and I eliminated irrelevant misleading material in the 2nd-to-last paragraph.  The rest of the answer is about radiated energy should be on point.

Comment: @Chris White: I changed "deep" to "steep".  I was addressing Atsby's comment.

Comment: @Ernie You have once sentence regarding my specific question and it has a vague qualifier. So I'm not sure what you would say, yes or no, does the golf ball radiate more energy *away from itself* per unit time than the smooth counterpart?

Comment: I've posted an answer with my current understanding. Please let me know if it's incorrect as yours is the only answer now which says a golf ball *will* radiate more.

Comment: I find your fourth paragraph obscure. It appears that you think that 50% of the radiation from any patch of a hemispherical dimple will be re-absorbed, which I agree with. However, you then seem to ignore this fact and focus on "normals", the importance of which is unclear as "normal" refers to solid angle with zero measure and therefore zero radiation. Since 50% of the radiation from the dimple will be reabsorbed and its area is $2\pi r^2$, it emits the same power as a flat patch of $\pi r^2$, IE the same as a flat cap to the dimple would emit.

Comment: @Samuel: Your answer is persuasive.  I'm still not convinced that the rate of radiation won't be slightly faster for a golf ball, but the weight of opinion is against me.  I will try to find out where my argument in paras 2,3,4 fails.  Thanks for the great question!

Comment: @Mark Eichenlaub: I should have called it a perpendicular line. It seems to me that energy radiated perpendicular to planes tangent to points on the surface of the dimple will clear the horizon of the dimple. 50% of energy radiated at all other angles won't clear the horizon.  The advantage of a golf ball is in rate of radiation, but I may be wrong.  I will edit the answer.

Comment: @Samuel:  I found my error and edited my answer.  Your answer and Mark's are correct.

Comment: @Mark Eichenlaub: My analysis was flawed.  Energy radiated perpendicular to tangents to the surface of the dimple, though it clears the horizon and is not reabsorbed, will be matched in amount by energy radiated from the surface of the smooth sphere where each dimple would have been.  Reduced cross section of a golf ball means less energy radiated away, and likewise discs over the dimples will radiate away less energy than the surface of a smooth sphere.  I corrected my answer.

Answer (score -1):

Without resorting to overt mathematics, it's clear that dimples won't help. Consider a radiating surface with uniform luminosity. Place a convex hemisphere with the same luminosity on the surface. What will it look like?

Consider the sun. We can only see one half of it, so it is effectively a hemisphere. It is not quite a perfect lambertian radiator, but it's pretty close, and it appears as a disk of almost uniform brightness. So a bump on a surface will look like a flat patch of the same brightness.

From symmetry, exactly the same effect will be seen with a concave hemisphere - ie, a dimple.

So a dimpled blackbody radiator will appear to be smooth, and dimples don't change the total radiated power.

This is not true for non-lambertian radiators, and real-world surfaces are not perfectly lambertian, but in this ideal case, dimples don't count.

Oh, well, there is a slight difference in the case of bumps rather than dimples - the apparent diameter of the body increases by some fraction of the height of the bumps, so there is a slight increase in radiation for this case. Likewise, the apparent diameter of the sphere is diminished by the slight loss of the "caps" for the dimples, and this will slightly reduce total radiation, but I doubt that's under consideration here.

Comment: I think you may be considering photometric qualities, rather than thermodynamic qualities.  Radiant intensity is the radiant flux per unit solid angle (a "disc" subtended by a cone with apex at the viewer.  Surface dimples wouldn't matter in that case.  But radiant exitance is thermodynamic flux emitted per unit surface area.  Exitance is not brightness, and I think you may be talking about brightness.  I may be missing something.

Comment: @Ernie, I may be missing something too, but if black bodies A and B are both the same temperature, and both the same shape and size, and if A radiates more power, then how could it _not_ look brighter?